# Clone and equal method in Eiffel

Tags: c#, eiffel

Why define a `clone` or `equal` method in Eiffel gives greater protection with respect to types problems in comparison to something similar in C#?

Comment: My brain is throwing exceptions attempting to parse this question.

Answer (score 2):

`clone` and `equal` don't offer anything great actually. These 2 routines are on their way out, replaced respectively by `twin` and the operator `~` in the latest estudio versions.

The problem with both of these routines was that don't offer great protection. The both take objects of type `ANY` (which is a problem). Their new counterparts are much safer and provide better control at compile time.